# I am changing the state management of my flutter app to getx and I ran into an issue with changing the state of the app after dropdown selection

Tags: flutter, state-management, flutter-getx

I am new getx and would appreciate if anyone can help me with this. I have dropdown that changes the state of the screen based on the dropdown chosen. It is working fine with setstate but I want to change the state management of my app to getx.
Here is my controller:

```
List<String>clientType = [
    'Anonymous',
    'New',
    'Existing Client',
    if (getIt<Data>().isAdmin()) 'Existing Account',
  ].obs;

void changeClientType(String value) {
    existingAccount = false;
    if (value == 'Existing Account') {
      existingAccount = true;
      for (int i = 0; i < products.length; i++)
        if (products[i].inventoryId.isEmpty) {
          Get.snackbar(
            'Error',
            'Please note that you cannot use "Quick Add" while selling to '
                'existing accounts. All "Quick Add" items will be skipped. '
                'To undo, change "client type" back to '
                '"$clientTypeDropdownValue"',
          );
          break;
        }
    }
    
    if (value == 'New') {
      newPersonInputFocusNode.requestFocus();
    } else {
      Get.focusScope.unfocus();
    }
    clientTypeDropdownValue = value; 
    update();
  }
```

Here is the UI Screen:

```
Widget _clientTypeDropdown() {
    double options = getIt<Data>().isAdmin() ? 4 : 3;
    return DropdownSearch<String>(
      key: _clientTypeKey,
      maxHeight: (55 * options).toDouble(),
      mode: Mode.MENU,
      showSelectedItem: true,
      items: addSalesController.clientType,
      
      label: 'Select Client Type',
      onChanged: 
      (value) => addSalesController.changeClientType(value),
      
      selectedItem: addSalesController.clientTypeDropdownValue,
    );
  }
  Widget _newClientInput() {
    return TextFormField(
      controller: _newClientController,
      focusNode: _newPersonInputFocusNode,
      keyboardType: TextInputType.name,
      textCapitalization: TextCapitalization.words,
      decoration: textBorder('Enter new client\'s name'),
      validator: (value) {
        String val = value.trim();
        if (val.isEmpty) return 'Enter new client\'s name';
        if (val.length > 99) return 'Maximum length (100) exceeded';
        return null;
      },
    );
  }
  Widget _existingClientDropdown() {
    return FutureBuilder<void>(
      future: _isOthersLoaded,
      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<void> snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasError) return Message();
        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting)
          return Loading();

        double maxHeight = (_clients.length * 55).toDouble();
        bool longerThanScreen = false;
        if (maxHeight + 100 > MediaQuery.of(context).size.height) {
          longerThanScreen = true;
          maxHeight = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height - 100;
        }
        return DropdownSearch<Person>(
          maxHeight: maxHeight == 0 ? 55 : maxHeight,
          mode: Mode.MENU,
          label: 'Select Client',
          items: _clients,
          onChanged: (value) => _clientNameDropdownValue = value,
          selectedItem: _clientNameDropdownValue,
          showClearButton: true,
          validator: (v) => v == null ? 'Please select client' : null,
          showSelectedItem: true,
          compareFn: (item, selectedItem) => selectedItem == item,
          emptyBuilder: (_, __) => EmptyDropdown(),
          showSearchBox: longerThanScreen,
          searchBoxDecoration: InputDecoration(
            prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.search, size: 25),
            labelText: 'Search',
            isDense: true,
            border: OutlineInputBorder(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
            ),
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
  Widget _existingAccountDropdown() {
    return FutureBuilder<void>(
      future: _isOthersLoaded,
      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<void> snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasError) return Message();
        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting)
          return Loading();

        double maxHeight = (_companies.length * 55).toDouble();
        bool longerThanScreen = false;
        if (maxHeight + 100 > MediaQuery.of(context).size.height) {
          longerThanScreen = true;
          maxHeight = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height - 100;
        }
        return DropdownSearch<Company>(
          maxHeight: maxHeight == 0 ? 55 : maxHeight,
          mode: Mode.MENU,
          label: 'Select Account',
          items: _companies,
          onChanged: (company) => _clientAccountDropdownValue = company,
          selectedItem: _clientAccountDropdownValue,
          showClearButton: true,
          validator: (v) => v == null ? 'Please select account' : null,
          showSelectedItem: true,
          compareFn: (item, selectedItem) => selectedItem == item,
          emptyBuilder: (_, __) => EmptyDropdown(),
          showSearchBox: longerThanScreen,
          searchBoxDecoration: InputDecoration(
            prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.search, size: 25),
            labelText: 'Search',
            isDense: true,
            border: OutlineInputBorder(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
            ),
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
```

All suggestions are welcome as long as it is related to this problem. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I am new about GetX, too but I hope this will help you. You should wrap your widget with GetxBuilder if you wanna update anywhere in your app.

for example:

```
Container(
    child: GetBuilder<ControllerClassX>(
       init: ControllerClassX(), //init this just one time in your page.
       builder: (_) => Container(...), //this part will be updated if you trigger your function what has update(); keyword.
       ),
    ),
 ),
```

Answer (score 0):

You should wrap your widgets with Obx or GetBuilder widgets to rebuild widget tree after each change.
Depends on your variable in controller, you can use widgets. e.g. for observable widget you can use Obx() and for normal variables you can use getBuilder().

Reactive variables sample :

```
class Controller extends GetxController{
  var count = 0.obs;
  increment() => count++;
}

class Home extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(context) {
    // Instantiate your class using Get.put() to make it available for all "child" routes there.
    final Controller c = Get.put(Controller());
    return Scaffold(
      // Use Obx(()=> to update Text() whenever count is changed.
      appBar: AppBar(title: Obx(() => Text("Clicks: ${c.count}"))),
      ...
  }
}
```

Normal variables sample :

```
class Controller extends GetxController {
  int counter = 0;
  void increment() {
    counter++;
    update(); // use update() to update counter variable on UI when increment be called
  }
}

// On your Stateless/Stateful class, use GetBuilder to update Text when increment be called
GetBuilder<Controller>(
  init: Controller(), 
  builder: (_) => Text(
    '${_.counter}',
  ),
)
```